# how to avoid "undefined" inside a "for-loop" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I'm changing the innerHTML with a for loop, but some values returns undefined since there's not the same amount of instances. How can I set up the loop to skip the empty instances?

This is to change the content of all instances with the same class, the amount of instances vary upon the class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p class="TEXT1">000</p>
<p class="TEXT1">000</p>
<p class="TEXT2">000</p>
<p class="TEXT3">000</p>
<p class="TEXT3">000</p>
<p class="TEXT3">000</p>
<p class="TEXT4">000</p>
<p class="TEXT5">000</p>
<p class="TEXT5">000</p>
<p class="TEXT5">000</p>
<p class="TEXT5">000</p>


<script>

function CHANGE() {
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//"paragraphs" will be different content texts, not just the word with a number.
  document.getElementsByClassName("TEXT1")[i].innerHTML = "Paragraph 1";
  document.getElementsByClassName("TEXT2")[i].innerHTML = "Paragraph 2";
  document.getElementsByClassName("TEXT3")[i].innerHTML = "Paragraph 3";
  document.getElementsByClassName("TEXT4")[i].innerHTML = "Paragraph 4";
  document.getElementsByClassName("TEXT5")[i].innerHTML = "Paragraph 5";
}    
}
CHANGE();
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The expected result is to get:

Paragraph 1

Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3

Paragraph 3

Paragraph 3

Paragraph 4

Paragraph 5

Paragraph 5

Paragraph 5

Paragraph 5

The actual result I get is:

Paragraph 1

Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3

000

000

Paragraph 4

Paragraph 5

000

000

000

Javascript Console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Comment: Avoid calling `document.getElementsByClassName` inside the loop as it's an expensive operation that you are repeating again and again. Instead call it before you enter the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the amount of instances vary upon the class.

You could check the number of instances.

```
for (var el of document.getElementsByClassName("TEXT1"))
  el.innerHTML = "Paragraph 1";
```

For multiple classes and texts:

```
let change = (cls, text) => {
  for (var el of document.getElementsByClassName(cls))
    el.innerHTML = text; 
};

change('text1', 'paragraph 1');
change('text2', 'paragraph 2');
...
```

Comment: on Multiple classes and texts I get the this:
 _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for
Line: 3_

Comment: should be fixed with the braces

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for loop check this condition

```
for(// your loop condition){

      myVar = document.getElementsByClassName("TEXT")[i];

      if (typeof myVar !== 'undefined'){

           continue;

      }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instead start with the classNames and search for matching elements. Once you have these you can operate on them

```
function CHANGE() {
    // define the classnames for TEXT1, TEXT2, ... TEXT6
    for(let i=1;i<=6;i++){
      let className = "TEXT"+i
      // pickup the child elements with the matching class
      let nodes = document.getElementsByClassName(className)
      // change the text
      for(let j=0; j<nodes.length;j++){
        nodes[j].innerHTML="Paragraph "+i
      }
    }   
}
```

Alternatively if you just wanted to work from a list of classnames you could say

```
function CHANGE() {
 const classNames = ['TEXT1','TEXT2','TEXT3','TEXT4','TEXT5','TEXT6']
 classNames.forEach(name=>{
    let nodes = document.getElementsByClassName(name)
    let innerText = "Paragraph "+name.replace("TEXT","")
    for(let j=0; j<nodes.length;j++){
      nodes[j].innerHTML=innerText
  }
 }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to change all of the different categories of elements in one loop, nor should you be hardcoding the length of the loop or re-calculating the list of elements in every loop. Try this:

```
var text1Elements = document.getElementsByClassName("TEXT1");
for (var i = 0; i < test1Elements.length; i++) {
  text1Elements[i].innerHTML = "Paragraph 1";
}
```

Then repeat that for every different class of element you want to manipulate. Alternatively, give all these elements an extra, common class, and just find and loop through the results for that, using a regular expression to determine the number. I'll include this example using ES6 syntax, since it's more complex anyway:

```
// Each element has the 'paragraph' class; for instance, class="TEXT1 paragraph", class="TEXT2 paragraph", etc.
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.paragraph');
for (let element of elements) {
    const matcher = element.className.match(/^TEXT(\d+)/i);
    element.innerHTML = `Paragraph ${matcher[1]}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call document.getElementsByClassName, you are forcing the DOM to find and collect those elements. This makes for a slow web site. try something like this:

```
for (var i=1; i < 6; i++) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("TEXT" + i);
  for (var element of elements) {
    element.innerHTML = "Paragraph " + i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over indexes that are not present try this snippet:

```js
function change() {

    var classes = ['TEXT1', 'TEXT2', 'TEXT3', 'TEXT4', 'TEXT5'];
    var paragraphs = ['Paragraph 1', 'Paragraph 2', 'Paragraph 3', 'Paragraph 4', 'Paragraph 5', ];

    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(classes[i]);
  
        for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
           elements[j].innerHTML = paragraphs[i];
        }
  
    }    
}

window.onload = function() {
  change();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p class="TEXT1">000</p>
<p class="TEXT1">000</p>
<p class="TEXT2">000</p>
<p class="TEXT3">000</p>
<p class="TEXT3">000</p>
<p class="TEXT3">000</p>
<p class="TEXT4">000</p>
<p class="TEXT5">000</p>
<p class="TEXT5">000</p>
<p class="TEXT5">000</p>
<p class="TEXT5">000</p>

</body>
</html>
```